# Bootstrap tooltip doesn't works

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Here is my HTML. I have included all files but....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<a href="#" id="tip" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>

<script>
$function() {
$('#tip').popover('show');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

where is the error?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your script is missing an opening bracket:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {  // missing the opening bracket
    $('#tip').popover('show');
  });
</script>
```

**edit**

The html was not fully correct either.  The code below works for me.  And here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aD77n/) to also prove it does work :-)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="tip" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#tip').popover('show');
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added more detail in my answer.